# Importing openzeppelin contracts in foundry

Tags: openzeppelin, foundry

I was trying to follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNMfMxGxeag
and at 5:23 when he goes on to edit remappings - I have no "remappings" in foundry.tml. When I try to just put there what he put and run `forge build` i get:

```
The application panicked (crashed).
```

and

```
Backtrace omitted. Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display it.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

how can I make it work?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add remapping to a separate `remappings.txt` file instead of `foundry.toml`. (Seems like the instructions in video is a bit outdated).
Try to follow the instructions in https://w.mirror.xyz/mOUlpgkWA178HNUW7xR20TdbGRV6dMid7uChqxf9Z58

Answer (score 3):

For using npm/nodejs as your dependency manager, this is the correct remappings:

```toml
[profile.default]
remappings = [
    "@openzeppelin/contracts=node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/"
]
```

To use git submodules/`forge install` please note that the correct method is:

```bash
forge install openzeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts
```

> This points to the correct github repo and will install under the `lib` sub directory

You do not need a seperate `remappings.txt` file, this is an artifact for keeping compatibility with [dapptools](https://dapp.tools/)

Comment: can you specify a version?  What happens  if  breaking changes are introduced in the future?

Answer (score 1):

I followed the video & this is working fine for me. Here is my `foundry.toml`

```py
[profile.default]
src = 'src'
out = 'out'
libs = ['lib']

# See more config options https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/tree/master/config

remappings = ["@opensezppling/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/"]
```